# Windows Phone app giving error after uploading to store

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I created an app which plays encrypted videos.

> App reads encrypted videos from the SD Card and stores the decrypted
>   videos in `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` of the app.

*The app is functioning properly when I am debugging in my windows phone in both `Debug` and `Release` mode.*

But after uploading to the store app is not **decrypting** the video and giving error "**Decryption Failed**". Can anybody help?

Comment: Is it any permission issue

Comment: Thanks for reply. No... Means I don't think so as if there was any then app wouldn't have debugged in my device as well.

Comment: Did you look on you dashboard for stacktrace of the error

Comment: Sorry but I don't know where to look for that in dashboard. As app is not crashing, it gives an error message.

Comment: I think if there is no crash you couldn't get that, What you use for Decryption ?

Comment: I am using System.Security.Cryptography, FileStream and CryptoStream for decrypting and writing file.

Comment: Have you checked the manifest declares the correct requriements?

Comment: Yes I have check the requirements. But according to me the problem is not with decryption as it is decrypting the password. I think it is with writing file into ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder folder? I don't know, may be

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the answer. Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime doesn't support Filestream Read and Write, instead you need to use [CreateFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227250.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [GetFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfileasync), for creating and reading respectively.